# LED bulb driver

Tags: power-supply, inductor, led-driver

I am trying to make a non-isolated LED bulb driver and while reverse engineering I found the driver's inductor has three pins: one is connected to ground, one is connected to the FB pin of the driver IC, and the last one is connected to the output pin for the LEDs.

While reading in the [datasheet of the driver IC BP2339](http://www.bpsemi.com/uploads/file/20170527151227_619.pdf) I didn't find any help. If someone knows how the circuit works please help me.

Comment: Welcome!  Could you post a sketch of the circuit you've worked out?  And maybe a photo of the inductor you're describing.  You'll get the best from EE.SE with a lot of information about what you're seeing and doing, as otherwise we don't have much to work on.

Comment: The best thing to do is to post the photo of your circuit and the inductor. Chances are that the inductor has a "tap" which goes to feedback, but it is not suggested in the datasheet, so it's likely added by an engineer who designed the circuit for the bulb.